# Функция в С++ для проверки на простоту

Tags: c++, stl

Существует ли функция в С++ в STL для проверки, является ли число простым, и если да, то где про нее почитать? (или просто шаблон дайте)

Comment: Похожий вопрос - [Получить таблицу простых чисел во время компиляции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774045/Получить-таблицу-простых-чисел-во-время-компиляции/774237#774237)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандарте, вроде, нет.

Проверить можно, например, простым алгоритмом в лоб: перебрать все нечетные числа от 3 до sqrt(N), проверяя, не являются ли они делителями. Можно сделать алгоритм более хитрым, добавив к этому нечто вроде решета Эратосфена: если 3 не является делителем N, то, очевидно, никакое кратное 3 тоже не будет, позволяет, вроде бы, уменьшить число делений — за счет запоминания, какие делители уже можно не проверять.

Это простые способы.

Comment: RSA алгоритм генерации ключа, смотреть исходники, там все это есть

Comment: Ну понятно, но это уже серьезная математика ведь.

Comment: Не, оттуда можно вычленить проверку целых чисел, в масштабах комментария подробнее не опишешь, но в общем там не много. Только не OpenSSL смотреть, там дрова с логикой кода.

Comment: И коль зашла речь, RSA очень благодарный алгоритм, поменяв там немного, получаем неломаемую без исходников шифровалку :) по этому реализаций RSA масса, смотреть лучше на гитхабе, там и код по проще можно подобрать.

Comment: @NewView Это, как бы сказать... не совсем для того диапазона чисел, да и проверки там все же вероятностные.

Comment: @Harry, я имел в виду кусок кода по валидации простых чисел. Сейчас гляну старые наработки по RSA, если найду сходу, выложу.