# Рекурсивная инстанциация шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, рекурсия, шаблоны-с++

Инстанциация шаблонных классов в рекурсивных вызовах проходит полностью? То есть правда ли, что в этом случае вызов `IsPrime<9>::value` раскроется в `9%4 != 0 && 9%3 != 0 && 9%2 !=0`, потом вычислятся только 2 первых условия и в `value` запишется `false`, либо же, т.к. уже `ImplIsPrime<9,3>::value` даёт `false`, то `ImplIsPrime<9,2>` можно не инстанциировать? Другими словами, с точки зрения компилятора будут всегда выполнены `val/2 --> 2` инстанциации (грубо говоря, итерации цикла) или же до первого `false`?

```
template<unsigned int val, unsigned int div>
struct ImplIsPrime {
    static constexpr bool value = (val % div != 0) && ImplIsPrime<val, div - 1>::value;
};

template<unsigned int val>
struct ImplIsPrime<val, 2> {
    static constexpr bool value = (val % 2 != 0);
};

template<unsigned int val>
struct IsPrime {
    static constexpr bool value = ImplIsPrime<val, val / 2>::value;
};


int main() {
    bool is_9_prime = IsPrime<9>::value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, в вашем примере, несмотря на то что после вычисления `(val % div != 0)` ответ известен, выражение `ImplIsPrime<val, div - 1>::value` все равно будет интсанционировано, хотя бы для того чтобы определить существование константы value и её тип. Если хотите избежать интсанционирования вынесете условие ветвления в параметры шаблона, тогда будет инстанционироваться только нужная ветвь.

```
template<unsigned int val           ,
         unsigned int div           = val / 2,
         bool         non_dividable = (val % div != 0) >
struct ImplIsPrime ;

template<unsigned int val, unsigned int div >
struct ImplIsPrime <val, div, false>
           : std::integral_constant<bool, false>
{};

template<unsigned int val, unsigned int div >
struct ImplIsPrime <val, div, true>
           : ImplIsPrime<val, div - 1>
{}; 
template<unsigned int val>
struct ImplIsPrime<val, 1, false>
        : std::integral_constant<bool, true>
{};
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает для больших чисел

Comment: @jerry Вообще-то нет. Проблема с интенсивной рекурсией по-прежнему присутствует. В gcc максимальная глубина рекурсии всего 900.

Comment: @VTT ну это если большое простое число, а для больших непростых успевает найти делитель и выйти. Например, раньше `10000` ломалось, а теперь - нет. У меня специфика задачи такая, что такое решение с простым алгоритмом подойдёт

Answer (score 0):

`ImplIsPrime<9,3>::value` будет инстанцирован еще *до* вычисления значения просто потому что это часть выражения. То, что слева от `&&` будет false действительно позволяет не вычислять правую часть, но на ее инстанцирование это никак не влияет.

Comment: если так, то можно как-нибудь прекратить инстанцирование после `ImplIsPrime<9,3>::value`, чтобы время компиляции уменьшить?

Comment: @jerry Мне кажется, что тут надо скорее копать в сторону улучшения алгоритма. Например не проверять не все подряд числа-делители, а только простые. И избавляться от рекурсии. Вот вопрос по теме: [получить таблицу простых числел во время компиляции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774045/Получить-таблицу-простых-чисел-во-время-компиляции/774237#774237)